# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've moved my website from server to another, and I got an error when I try to visit the page of the quiz results. 
Error says:

Cannot handle this request.

After taking a look on my php error log I found this line:

```
[09-May-2019 08:19:13 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member 
function num_rows() on boolean in
/home/USER/public_html/PATH/PATH/models/Result_model.php on line 
143
```

This is the main part of the file content noting that I've commented on the referred line of 143 as :

```
function get_result($rid){
$logged_in=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$uid=$logged_in['uid'];
if($logged_in['su']=='0'){
$this->db->where('savsoft_result.uid',$uid);
}
$this->db->where('savsoft_result.rid',$rid);
 $this->db->join('savsoft_users','savsoft_users.uid=savsoft_result.uid');
$this->db->join('savsoft_group','savsoft_group.gid=savsoft_users.gid');
$this->db->join('savsoft_quiz','savsoft_quiz.quid=savsoft_result.quid');
$query=$this->db->get('savsoft_result');
return $query->row_array();


}


function last_ten_result($quid){
    $this->db->order_by('percentage_obtained','desc');
    $this->db->limit(10);       
    $this->db->where('savsoft_result.quid',$quid);
    $this->db->join('savsoft_users','savsoft_users.uid=savsoft_result.uid'); 
    $this->db->join('savsoft_quiz','savsoft_quiz.quid=savsoft_result.quid');
    $query=$this->db->get('savsoft_result');
    return $query->result_array();
}



function get_percentile($quid,$uid,$score){
$logged_in =$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$gid= $logged_in['gid'];
$res=array();
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.quid",$quid);
$this->db->group_by("savsoft_result.uid");
$this->db->order_by("savsoft_result.score_obtained",'DESC');
$query = $this -> db -> get('savsoft_result');
$res[0]=$query -> num_rows();    // THIS IS LINE 143


$this->db->where("savsoft_result.quid",$quid);
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.uid !=",$uid);
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.score_obtained <=",$score);
$this->db->group_by("savsoft_result.uid");
$this->db->order_by("savsoft_result.score_obtained",'DESC');
$querys = $this -> db -> get('savsoft_result');
$res[1]=$querys -> num_rows();

return $res;
```

Tried to fix this issue depending on some other questions here in StackOverFlow but couldn't .. all tries filed.

Anyone got the solution for this issue?

Comment: which is it: the function `num_rows()` doesn't exist or `num_rows()` on boolean? your question has conflicting problem statements. if it is the former then double check your system folder copied over correctly. if it is the later it means that your query failed (returned false instead of an object); check to make sure your database copied over correctly.

Comment: The database is working perfectly, everything in the website still works. This issue has appeared without making any changes to the website. The PHP error log says that the file has a line error. The function num_rows() is already exist.

Comment: The log file you referenced appears to be an old typo of `db->num_rows()`, since `db->get()`  returns the results of [`db->query()`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1.10/system/database/DB_driver.php#L608). The current error means the query returned by [`db->get()`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1.10/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L1370) is true or false instead of a [`CI_DB_mysqli_result`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1.10/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php#L58)

Comment: I am noob at codeigniter.. I've used this: $res[0]=$this->db->num_rows();  So I got this issue: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::num_rows()

Comment: but the code you have listed is `$query->num_rows()` which is correct... whereas db->num_rows isnt

Comment: Really don't know.. All of the website functions are working without issues. only this appeared out of sudden

Comment: Ah, got that. Sorry had this written by mistake. Fixed the error name in my question.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Test the return result of `var_dump($this->db->get('savsoft_result')); exit;` if it is `false` the query is failing. You would need to then use `if (!$this->db->get('savsoft_result')) { var_dump($this->db->error()); exit; }` To determine why it is failing. For more info see https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#handling-errors

Comment: it gave me false.. after dumping the error I got this : array(2) { ["code"]=> int(1055) ["message"]=> string(239) "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'savaraed.savsoft_result.rid' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" }

Comment: It seems like server side. I've tried to install the same script as fresh with new database, created a quiz and tested the result and it gave me the same error.

Comment: It looks like the new server is using `MySQL 5.7` which enables [`only_full_group_by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) by default.  I believe you may be able to use [`$this->db->count_all_results('savsoft_result')`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results) See the `only_full_group_by` link i provided for details on why you are getting the error and how to avoid it.

Comment: You're right, the old MySQL version was 5.6 and I never faced issued with. After trying what you suggested in your last reply, The error changed to : PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function num_rows() on integer

Comment: Yes you don't need `$query->num_rows()`, instead replace `$query = $this->db->get('savsoft_result')` with  `$res[0]= $this->db->count_all_results('savsoft_result');` and remove `$res[0]=$query -> num_rows();` Be sure to verify the results, as I have not used `count_all_results`

Comment: It gave the old same error ( on boolean )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193068/discussion-between-fyrye-and-b-happy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in our chat, the issue is caused by the server migration and the new server using MySQL 5.7+ which enables [`only_full_group_by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) by default.

The reason is that MySQL is not able to select a determinant value related to the groupings, and errors instead of silently ignoring the potentially undesired value(s) in the `SELECT` statement, as it did in prior versions of MySQL.

For example: `SELECT customer, SUM(order_total) FROM orders GROUP BY purchase_date`

If two or more customers have the same `purchase_date`, only one can be shown and MySQL needs to determine which one you want.

Since CodeIgniter defaults to using `SELECT *` for the statement when using `$this->db->get()`, the error is encountered.

To resolve the issue, it is highly recommended to update **all** of your `GROUP BY` related queries, in the entire application, to be MySQL 5.7 compatible. This will ensure you are retrieving the correct values from your `GROUP BY` statements.

There are a few options you can use, in order of least complex and most beneficial.

**1)** Use [`$this->db->count_all_results()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results) instead of `$query->num_rows()` 
 *(aka: `SELECT COUNT(*)`)*

```
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.quid",$quid);
$this->db->group_by("savsoft_result.uid");
$res[0] = $this->db->count_all_results('savsoft_result');

$this->db->where("savsoft_result.quid",$quid);
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.uid !=",$uid);
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.score_obtained <=",$score);
$this->db->group_by("savsoft_result.uid");
$res[1] = $this->db->count_all_results('savsoft_result');
```

*Note the removal of `order_by` as it is not needed to count the rows.*

**2)** Limit the values to only those grouped

```
$this->db->select('savsoft_result.uid');
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.quid",$quid);
$this->db->group_by("savsoft_result.uid");
$this->db->order_by("savsoft_result.score_obtained",'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get('savsoft_result');
$res[0] = $query->num_rows();

$this->db->select('savsoft_result.uid');
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.quid",$quid);
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.uid !=",$uid);
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.score_obtained <=",$score);
$this->db->group_by("savsoft_result.uid");
$this->db->order_by("savsoft_result.score_obtained",'DESC');
$querys = $this->db->get('savsoft_result');
$res[1] = $querys->num_rows();
```

**3)** Explicitly define [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) for all non-grouped columns

 *(This is the equivalent of disabling `only_full_group_by`)*

Using the query I provided above.

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(customer), SUM(order_total) FROM orders GROUP BY purchase_date
```

So you should be able to use something like the following, be sure to add ALL of the non-grouped columns in the related table.

```
$this->db->select('ANY_VALUE(savsoft_result.quid), ANY_VALUE(savsoft_result.score_obtained), savsoft_result.uid');
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.quid",$quid);
$this->db->group_by("savsoft_result.uid");
$this->db->order_by("savsoft_result.score_obtained",'DESC');
$query = $this -> db -> get('savsoft_result');
$res[0] = $query->num_rows();

$this->db->select('ANY_VALUE(savsoft_result.quid), ANY_VALUE(savsoft_result.score_obtained), savsoft_result.uid');
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.quid",$quid);
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.uid !=",$uid);
$this->db->where("savsoft_result.score_obtained <=",$score);
$this->db->group_by("savsoft_result.uid");
$this->db->order_by("savsoft_result.score_obtained",'DESC');
$querys = $this->db->get('savsoft_result');
$res[1] = $querys->num_rows();
```

---

Alternatively you can disable the `only_full_group_by` sql_mode.

You can ***temporarily*** disable it by updating the global variable, by executing a `SET GLOBAL` statement.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','')));
```

This will retrieve the currently used `sql_mode` and remove the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` portion, then remove any leading or trailing comma that remains. However once the MySQL service is restarted, you will need to execute the statement again.

To ensure `only_full_group_by` does not revert back to enabled when the MySQL service is restarted, edit your `my.cnf` MySQL configuration file, to omit the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the `sql_mode` declaration.

You can retrieve the current `sql_mode` by executing the statement

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

Which should return something like:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Copy the entire text, then declare the `sql_mode` in the `my.cnf` file, removing the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` portion.

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

After making the change to the `my.cnf` file, restart the MySQL service.